# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'subject'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a simple application to manage to-do tasks.

[image: Todo]

I am trying to populate the text and combobox widgets with the selected item's attributes, but having no success because apparently it's returning none.

I am getting:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/Todo/Todo.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Todo/Todo.py", line 233, in edit_item
    self.subject_text = task.subject
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'subject'
```

Here is my Task class:

```
class Task:

    def __init__(self, subject, priority):

        self.subject = subject
        self.priority = priority
```

... and here is the function in question:

```
def edit_item(self):

    if len(self.listbox.curselection()) > 0:
        self.edit_button.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.save_button.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.create_add_dialog()

        task = self.find_task(self.listbox.get(ACTIVE))
        self.subject_text = task.subject
        self.priority_combobox = task.priority

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Make sure you have tasks selected!')
        self.edit_button.config(state=DISABLED)

def find_task(self, task):

    for x in self.tasks:
        if x.subject == task:
            return x
```

How can I overcome the issue?

Comment: What does the `Listbox` contain?

Comment: I posted a picture?

Comment: What is the format of `self.tasks`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. It's a list of Task objects.

Comment: Did you make sure that`Task` object has a "subject" class variable if it is a class? If not a class, what is it?

Comment: If ```find_task``` does not find anything it will return None.

Comment: Yeah but how can it not find anything? That's the real question.

Answer (score 0):

In `find_task`, you iterate over the list of tasks, and if there's a match, you return the task. However it returns `None` if there isn't. So you should check that the task exists before you get the class variables:

```
task = self.find_task(self.listbox.get(ACTIVE))
if task:
    self.subject_text = task.subject
    self.priority_combobox = task.priority
else:  #no such task
    #example
    messagebox.showinfo("Notification","There is no such task named %s"%(self.listbox.get(ACTIVE)))
```

Comment: ...but how is it possible that there isn't such a task, when there is? That's my question.

Comment: Did you make sure that there is a `Task` class with **"test (High)"** as the subject?